# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{ \sin^nx + 2}{x^{2n} + 1}}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> Calculate the radius of convergence of  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{ \sin^nx + 2}{x^{2n} + 1}}$

When I tried, I got that $-1 < x < 1$ and when checking edges ($x=-1,x=1$) the two were divergent.

Is that correct?

Comment: $\sin(x^n+2)$ or $\sin(x^n)+2$ or $(\sin x)^n+2$?

Comment: the third, sorry. edited.

Comment: This is not a power series so we may say about the set of convergence only. If $|x| \le 1$, then the necessary condition of convergence of a number series fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say anything for the radius of convergence because you are not dealing with a power series. However, as you've already noticed the series diverges for $ |x|\le 1$ because
$$
\frac{\sin^nx+2}{x^{2n}+1} \ge \frac12 \quad \forall |x|\le 1.
$$
For $|x|>1$ the series converges because we have
$$
\frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}\le \frac{\sin^nx+2}{x^{2n}+1} \le 3\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^n \quad \forall |x|>1
$$

Answer (score 1):

First at all note that the given series isn't a power series so you can't tell about the radius of convergence but rather we look for the set of $x$ for which the series is well defined.

A **necessary condition** for the convergence of the series is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ \sin^nx + 2}{x^{2n} + 1}=0\iff |x|>1$$
Now we verify that **this condition is suffisant**:

$$\left|\frac{ \sin^nx + 2}{x^{2n} + 1}\right|\leq \frac{3}{x^{2n}}=3 \left(x^{-2}\right)^n=v_n$$
so for $|x|>1$ the given series is (*absolutely*) convergent by comparison with the geometric convergent series $\displaystyle \sum_n v_n$ and we conclude:

$$\text{  the given series is defined for }\ x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup (1,+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't give it a radius of convergence because it's not of the form $\sum a_n x^n$.

For $x=0$, you get $\sum 2$ which obvious diverges.

But for $x=\pi$, you get $\sum \cfrac{2}{\pi^{2n}+1}$ which converges.

So a radius of convergence would be of little help since it wouldn't tell you anything about what converges and what does not.